# SSL AWS EC2 backend with S3 frontend

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a VueJS front-end application running on S3 being served as a static website.

I have a NodeJS (behind an nginx reverse proxy, plus a few other services) backend application running on an EC2 instance that the VueJS app talks to (over http currently).

I have a domain successfully pointed at the VueJS app (S3 bucket) with the configured SSL certificates using Route53 / CloudFront / ACM.

However, now the VueJS app will not communicate with the EC2 instance backend as it is still using HTTP which is now not allowed.

So what is the best way to configure this?  I can't run certbot on the ec2 instance and generate an SSL certificate for my domain as there are certificates already being used for the S3 bucket.

Should I just create a self-signed certificate?

Can I create another certificate for a subdomain perhaps (`api.example.com` say) and set up DNS record for that to point to my EC2 instance IP address?

How is this usually done, what is best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a self-sign cert wont work, it wont pass validation as there is no known CA behind it ( Certificate authority) I mean you can install it but the browser is going to complain..

Im not sure I understand why you cant use certbot.. s3 / ec2 are two seperate services so I'm a bit confused here?

You can use letencrypt to generate a cert for the server and have it installed as well but if you have clusters you may be better served by installing it on the actual ALB, however this does not ensure end-to-end if the cert is not installed on all backend systems, (that would require installing the cert on all systems in the cluster) You requirements will dictate this really.

If you are unable to generate a cert with letsencrypt you can get an SSL from ssls.com and just installed the PEM or CRT on the server / load balancer too though.

Comment: So I have already created certs for `*.example.com` and `example.com` on ACM for the S3 front-end.  I wasn't sure how to create a separate one like `api.example.com` for example for EC2 backend.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but its going to depend if you want to buy or get a free one. ssls.com will allow you to buy one for as little as like 5.00 letsencrypt is free as well but needs to be installed on the ec2 instance and configured but both will work. Then you just need to tell the server where the cert is or export and place on the ALB

Comment: Thanks.  Ok so I created another A record in Route 53 `api.example.com` pointing to my EC2 IP and then ran certbot on that domain.  That seems to have worked now thanks.

Comment: If it's encrypted till it hits your load balancer, that meets the definition of weak form E2E encryption, as the load balancer is the edge of your system. It doesn't need to remain encrypted INSIDE your system as once it hits the LB it can't be intercepted anymore, you're essentially communicating over a local network. unless you're implementing strong form E2E encryption (IE my server has no idea what's in the request), in which case whether the cert is on the LB or the server really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you create some subdomain like you said for your api and create a certificate for that subdomain. On AWS in particular, you can use an elastic load balancer and use ACM /Route53 with that for ease of certificate management, but that does carry costs of the load balancer.

Alternative is to just put an API gateway in front of your EC2 instance as a reverse proxy, which will carry some costs, but maybe not as much depending on traffic volume.

Comment: Will look into ALB thanks.  Was hoping to config a cert with nginx but may be more involved.

Comment: you can do it either way. ELB is just a little less manual

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to create a cert with certbot on the ec2 instance after creating the necessary dns record.  All seems to be working now without needing ELB.

Comment: Yes, you do not need ELB, never meant to imply you did. I was saying you CAN use ELB to make some things easier.